# IAuthenticationRequest.RedirectToProvider is not supposed to return, yet it does

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

The method `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.IAuthenticationRequest.RedirectToProvider()` is documented never to return:

> Redirects the user agent to the
>   provider for authentication. Execution
>   of the current page terminates after
>   this call.

However, it does return under the latest implementation (3.4.3). I'm using the following code:

```
using (var relayingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
{
  var response = relayingParty.GetResponse();

  if (response == null)
  {
    // Stage 2: user submitting Identifier
    var openId = Request.Form["openId"];
    relayingParty.CreateRequest(openId).RedirectToProvider();

    throw new Exception("Never gets here");
  }

  ...
}
```

(The line with "Never gets here" is reached). I need to return an ActionResult from this method ...

1. Is this a known bug?
2. Is there a aorkaround? Should I return EmptyResult?

As far as I understand this is a bug - [I submitted it](http://trac.dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/193) in the project issue tracker.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, you should use this code:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging; // required for the extension method to work

    return relyingParty.CreateRequest(openid).RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

Apparently ASP.NET usually throws an exception as a result of the `RedirectToProvider()` call, but not always.  But the above code will work and is more MVC friendly.

Comment: Does not compile.

'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponse' does not contain a definition for 'AsActionResponse'

Comment: Did you add the using statement at the top of your file?  And are you targeting .NET 3.5?

Comment: adding `using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;` worked for me thanks